# DLL Load Failed when running kivy pong tutorial

Tags: python, installation, kivy

I have been trying to learn python and create a small application using kivy to become introduced to kivy python apps.  But I cannot even get the pong tutorial that comes with the standard kivy installation to work.  I get the following output when I run the file pong.py in the examples folder.

```
botstrapping Kivy @ C:\Users\myname\Applications\Kivy\
Setting Environment Variables:
#################################
GST_REGISTRY
C:\Users\myname\Applications\Kivy\gstreamer\registry.bin
---------------
GST_PLUGIN_PATH:
C:\Users\myname\Applications\Kivy\gstreamer\lib\gstreamer-0.10
---------------
PATH:
C:\Users\myname\Applications\Kivy\;C:\Users\myname\Applications\Kivy\Python;C:
\Users\myname\Applications\Kivy\Python\Scripts;C:\Users\myname\Applications\Ki
vy\gstreamer\bin;C:\Users\myname\Applications\Kivy\MinGW\bin;C:\Perl\site\bin;C
:\Perl\bin;C:\Program Files\ActiveState Perl Dev Kit 9.2.1\bin\;C:\Program Files
\ActiveState Komodo Edit 7\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\
Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\Windows
PowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Progra
m Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\P
rogram Files\Autodesk\Backburner\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\
;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft A
SP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Perform
ance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program F
iles\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\Program File
s\Perforce
----------------------------------
PYTHONPATH:
C:\Users\myname\Applications\Kivy\kivy;
----------------------------------
##################################
done bootstraping kivy...have fun!\n
running "python.exe C:\Users\myname\Applications\Kivy\kivy\examples\tutorials\p
ong\main.py" \n
[INFO              ] Kivy v1.5.1
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\myname\.kivy\logs\ki
vy_13-02-15_11.txt
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 137 symbols loaded
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=
Nones
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.image> with limit=None, timeout
=60s
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.atlas> with limit=None, timeout
=Nones
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.texture> with limit=1000, timeo
ut=60s
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.shader> with limit=1000, timeou
t=3600s
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\myname\Applications\Kivy\kivy\examples\tutorials\pong\main.py
", line 4, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "C:\Users\myname\Applications\Kivy\kivy\kivy\app.py", line 222, in <mod
ule>
     from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
   File "C:\Users\myname\Applications\Kivy\kivy\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 86, i
n <module>
     from kivy.graphics import Canvas
   File "C:\Users\myname\Applications\Kivy\kivy\kivy\graphics\__init__.py", lin
e 76, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics.instructions import Callback, Canvas, CanvasBase, \
   File "vbo.pxd", line 8, in init kivy.graphics.instructions (kivy\graphics\ins
tructions.c:11678)
   File "texture.pxd", line 3, in init kivy.graphics.vbo (kivy\graphics\vbo.c:43
61)
   File "texture.pyx", line 1, in init kivy.graphics.texture (kivy\graphics\text
ure.c:11112)
   File "opengl_utils.pyx", line 19, in init kivy.graphics.opengl_utils (kivy\gr
aphics\opengl_utils.c:3717)
 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
Press any key to continue . . ."
```

I believe the failure is coming during the statement:

```
from opengl import _GL_GET_SIZE
```

But I am unsure as to why this is not working and why it is failing to load even their premade tutorial.  Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Ensure you are using the latest graphics driver for your GPU from the GPU vendor, Kivy needs a Graphics driver that suports OpenGLES2.0 minimum. The drivers provided by default on windows are the Microsoft drivers that mostly only support OpenGL ES 1.1.

Comment: Yeah i have the current drivers installed for my nvidia card and ive coded for opengl3 before so they are compliant with at least opengl3.  But thatnk you for the suggestion.

Comment: You should post this on the kivy-users mailing list along with the details of your system, os version, gpu and driver version. Info on How did you install kivy? using the package provided from kivy.org/downloads or some other source? Did you have python installed previously... You will get more precise help on the kivy-users https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/kivy-users mailing list.

Comment: Thank you qua-non.  I will do that.  I downloaded kivy using the zip they have on their webpage.  And I do have another installation of the python language.  I will be sure to post this issue on the kivy user forums with the information you suggested.